# Find all possible pairs in an array

Tags: java, recursion

Its when I try to do stuff like this I realise I really need to go to university!

Anyway I have an array of strings (275) I need to loop through them and create strings of all the possible pairs, in Java.

I've been learning about recursion but I cant find the answer for this.

Comment: Why recursion? A double for-statement would do the trick.

Comment: Given an array `[a,b,c]`, do you want to create: `[ab,ac,ba,bc,ca,cb]`? Or are `ab` and `ba` the same?

Comment: I believe you'll find the answer after you've been learning about bubble sort.

Comment: Why mention bubble sorting ? The question isn't even about sorting.

Comment: See also functional solution in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345168/how-to-find-object-pairs-in-the-same-list-in-java-in-a-good-way

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In case pairs `ab` and `ba` are different, do:

```
for i=0 to array.length
  for j=0 to array.length
    if i == j skip
    else construct pair array[i], array[j]
```

and if not, do something like this:

```
for i=0 to array.length-1
  for j=i+1 to array.length
    construct pair array[i], array[j]
```

Note that I am assuming the array holds unique strings!

Comment: Hi.. i need exactly the same thing.. But i ahve a large array(say with size of 10^9).. It is taking long time to respond.. is there any optimized way?

Comment: Only possible optimization I'd see here (first case) is to remove the if test, and after the loops, remove the n additional objects where `i==j` (If you can do this with the data structure you selected). This way you don't have to perform `n^2` times the i==j check. But then, maybe the JVM is already optimizing this some better way.
Then, if you can afford some multithreading or cloud computing, you can always split the loops across several threads/servers

Answer (score 2):

It's a simple double-loop:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 275; x++) {
    final String first = arrayOfStrings[x];
    for(int y = 0; y < 275; y++) {
        if(y == x) continue; // will properly increase y
        final String second = arrayOfStrings[y];
        // TODO: do stuff with first and second.
    }
}
```

Edit: as the comments noted, if the elements `[a, b, c]` have only one `ab` and thus not `ba`, (called permutation), then the following code will work:

```
final ArrayList<String> collected = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int x = 0; x < 275; x++) {
    for(int y = 0; y < 275; y++) {
        if(y == x) continue; // will properly increase y
        final String p1 = arrayOfStrings[x] + arrayOfStrings[y];
        final String p2 = arrayOfStrings[y] + arrayOfStrings[x];
        if(!collected.contains(p1) && !collected.contains(p2)) {
            collected.add(p1);
        }
    }
}
// TODO: do stuff with collected
```

Answer (score 2):

I am providing an example that prints all possible n-tuples Strings, just set the attribute reqLen to 2 and it prints all possible pairs.

```
public class MyString {

String[] chars = {"a", "b", "c"};
int reqLen = 2;

private void formStrings(String crtStr){

    if (crtStr.length() == reqLen){

        System.out.println(crtStr);
        return;
    }
    else
        for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) 
            formStrings(crtStr + chars[i]);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    new MyString().formStrings("");
}}
```

Answer (score -1):

Time Complexity -> o(n^2)

```
public class LogAllParisOfArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<array.length;j++){
                System.out.println(array[i] + " "+array[j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't a correct answer. [1,1] is not a pair contained in [1,2,3,4,5,6].