# Searching within Pair in java

Tags: java, search, collections

I want to search for particular `String` elements within a `Pair<String,int>`.I am using the simple `equals` method to do this. Please suggest me any other useful technique for this. The `String` list is having at least 10000 elements.

```
for (String str1 : StringList) {
    for (Pair<?, ?> pair : nodeList) {
        if (pair.getFirst().equals(str1)) {
            // Some code here...            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to search for a String among 10000 Strings?

Comment: what operation you want to perform after finding pair?

Comment: possible duplicate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392652/java-find-all-possible-pairs-in-an-array

Comment: I also think to use HashSet instead of List but doen't know how it took even more time than with the list.

Comment: @engineer2014: Could you paste the entire code? It's not very clear what you're trying to do. There's no way that it will take longer with a `HashSet`.

Answer (score 3):

I think you shold use a `HashMap` for this. It contains pairs like key->value and you can easy check existance of both with `containsKey` and `containsValue` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to repeatedly check if your `StringList` contains a particular `String`, you'd be better off using a `HashSet<String>` instead.

Use the [HashSet.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) method to check if your string exists - this way, you'll get the return value immediately in O(1) time instead of having to iterate over all the elements.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a sequential scan on >10000 records and performing a String.equals() operation will be slow. Consider using a HashMap instead, where keys are the first (string) in each pair, values are the second (integer):

```
Map<String, Integer> map = //... get your map

for (String str : stringList) {
   Integer found = map.get(str);
   if (found!=null) {
      // Some code here...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `HashSet` instead of a List. It brings the complexity down to O(n) instead of the O(n^2) you have now.

Comment: How can we get pair after using HashSet?

Comment: A set would actually help, but would need a custom equals and hashCode, so it's not as trivial as your answer puts it out to be.

Comment: @pcalcao Looks to be Strings he's using, and they already have a proper equals and hashCode.

Comment: No, he's using Pair of Strings. Pair will use the default hashCode and equals of Object. He wants to find the Pair where the first element is equal to a String. Also, your complexities are completely wrong.

Comment: @pcalcao True, a HashMap mapping the first String to the pair would be needed if he needs to get the Pair object (although he hasn't specified what processing he will perform). What's wrong with the complexities? An inner loop is O(n^2) and since hashset (or hashmap's containsKey) is O(1), that would bring it down to O(n).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to search for a particular Pair of Strings in a List. That particular Pair first element must match the String you are looking for, correct?

Well, if your list is not ordered in any way, you're out of luck. Go through all the elements and search for it.

If the List is ordered (in order of the first element of the Pair), then you can use a Binary Search to do it blazingly faster.